# Modifying website through email

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to try to do something where I can make changes to my site based on emails received to the sites email. Does anyone know how to do that?

I want something where if its from a specific email address, and follows a particular format, it will change a certain part of the site according to the contents of the email.

Comment: What advantages will this approach have over a CMS running via the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. 
You need:

1. Script that parses emails on schedule and adds those changes to some type of database
2. Script that executes updates from the temporary database and adds that data to live database

How to read email with PHP:

```
$mb = imap_open("{host:port/imap}","username", "password" );

$messageCount = imap_num_msg($mb);
for( $MID = 1; $MID <= $messageCount; $MID++ )
{
   $EmailHeaders = imap_headerinfo( $mb, $MID );
   $Body = imap_fetchbody( $mb, $MID, 1 );
   doSomething( $EmailHeaders, $Body );
}
```

[read more](http://ca.php.net/imap)

Comment: 3. A method to be reasonably sure that email forgeries don't allow arbitrary attackers to modify your web site.

Comment: How would you access the email to parse it?

Comment: I added more info. PS - I am sure that you know what to do, but I think it would be better to create a page where user enters his name/password and adds article directly. Parsing emails IMHO is a dumb idea.

Answer (score 1):

You would need some server side processing to be able to do this. [This thread](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10376231-RESOLVED-Setup-Email-Account-to-Run-PHP-Script) has a couple of ways of doing this using PHP, made easier with cPanel to make changes to the mail redirects. If you tell us more about your site and hosting environment, we may be able to give better suggestions.

The server side script would need to then parse your email and perform whatever updates your commands intend. Security is also very important, and it is trivial to forge the 'From' address when sending email.

Comment: Im just experimenting at the moment and trying to allow a user to change the text in the html through emails of a specific format. I dont have everything figure out yet though.